# Where does the norm come from in the definition of differentiability?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. We define $\triangledown f(x) \in M_{n \times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ , the instantaneous rate of change of $f$ at $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, as the linear transformation matrix such that $\triangledown f(x) x = f(x)$ and $\triangledown f(x) (x+h) = f(x+h)$ as $h \to 0$. Or, by linearity, as $$\triangledown f(x) \in M_{n \times 1}{\mathbb{(R)}}:\lim_{h \to 0} \triangledown f(x) (x + h - x) = \lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h) - f(x)$$
$$\triangledown f(x) \in M_{n \times 1}{\mathbb{(R)}}:\lim_{h \to 0} \triangledown f(x)h  = \lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h) - f(x)$$
$$\triangledown f(x) \in M_{n \times 1}{\mathbb{(R)}}:\lim_{h \to 0} f(x+h) - f(x) - \triangledown f(x)h = 0$$

In this case we say $f$ is *differentiable* at $x$, because it has an instantaneous rate of change at $x$.

However, in the definition of differentiability I am presented with, the norm is unaccountably present. I.e. $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x$  if

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \cfrac{f(x+h)-f(x) - \triangledown f(x)h}{|h|} = 0 $$

Where am I going wrong?

**Edit**
A lot of answers are emphasizing the importance of the norm in taking multivariate limits. That I understand. Let me try to recast the question.
We define the (average) rate of change between $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with respect to $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ as the linear transformation matrix $T$ such that $T(y-x) = f(y) - f(x)$; the *instantenous* rate of change, it would seem to follow, as the linear transformation matrix $T$ such that

$\lim_{y \to x} T(y-x) - f(y) - f(x) = 0$

Where does the norm show up in this reasoning (besides implicity, in the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition)?

Comment: In your first formulation, note that $h$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So what does it mean for $h$ to tend to zero? It must tend to zero in all directions (for example, we can't just say the first component of $h$ tends to zero), and to require that the norm tend to zero is one way of enforcing this.

Comment: The first "definition" looks very wrong. The derivative (if it exists) is defined as the (necessarily unique) linear transformation $T$ such that $f(x+h) - f(x) = T(h) + \mathcal{o}(\lVert h\rVert)$ as $h \to 0$. In other words, the second formulation is the right definition.

Comment: @paulinho Alright. But how does that work its way into a formulation of the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that as peek-a-boo noted, the first definition (assuming $h$ tends to the zero vector) isn't even correct, as this limit tends to zero even if $\nabla f$ is not the correct derivative. Let $\mathbf{h} = (p, q)$. For example, if $f$ is smooth, the definition you gave will assert that $\nabla f = [4, 2]$ at the origin if $f = x + y$, because
$$\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}} f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h} = \lim_{p, q \to 0} p + q - 4p - 2q = \lim_{p, q \to 0} -3p - q = 0$$
What we want is for this difference to not only tend to zero, but to tend to zero faster than a linear function of $\mathbf{h}$. If this is true, then as we take $\mathbf{h}$ closer and closer to $\mathbf{0}$, then $\nabla f \cdot h$ dominates $f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x})$, so $f(\mathbf{x + h})$ is approximated to leading order by $f(\mathbf{x}) + \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h}$. Note that above, the difference $f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h}$ is a linear function of $\mathbf{h}$, so it is not what we are looking for.

Up till this point, I haven't completely been thorough about what it means to "decay faster than linearly." For a smooth-enough function $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ to decay faster than linearly around the origin is to have for any linear function $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$,
$$\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{| g(\mathbf{h}) |}{|A \mathbf{h}|} = 0$$
barring the cases where $A \mathbf{h} = 0$. In other words, for any $A$, as long as we are close enough to the origin, $g(\mathbf{h})$ is *significantly* closer to zero than $A \mathbf{h}$.

Interestingly, a way to enforce that a given function $g(\mathbf{h})$ decays faster than linearly around the origin is to mandate that $|g(\mathbf{h})| / \|\mathbf{h}\|$ tends to zero, because for any linear transformation $A$,
$$\frac{\|A \mathbf{h}\|}{\|\mathbf{h}\|} \geq \lambda$$
for a fixed, finite, positive value of $\lambda$ (it is actually the smallest positive singular value of $A$). So it follows that
$$\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{| g(\mathbf{h}) |}{|A \mathbf{h}|} \leq \lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{| g(\mathbf{h}) |}{\lambda \|\mathbf{h}\|}$$
and hence if $|g(\mathbf{h})| / \|\mathbf{h}\|$ tends to zero, then so does the left-hand side of the above equation. Thus, by choosing $g = f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h}$ for any $\mathbf{x}$, it follows from what we've discussed that if
$$\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}} \frac{|f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h}|}{\|\mathbf{h}\|} = 0$$
then the numerator decays faster than linearly, which is exactly what we want in defining the derivative. This above, is usually given as the definition of $f$ being differentiable. (Note that you may see it without the absolute value in the numerator, but the two are equivalent.)

**EDIT:** What is the reason for wanting $\nabla f$ to be such that $f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h}$ to decay faster than linearly?

**Answer:** This is how we generalize the definition of the derivative. In one dimension, one might say the motivation for calculating a derivative of some smooth function $f$ at some point $x_0$ is to *linearize* $f$ around $x_0$, i.e. *best* approximate the function as a line going thru $(x_0, f(x_0))$. Linearizing the function is equivalent to finding a linear transformation $L$ such that $f(x_0) + L(x - x_0)$ *best* approximates $f(x)$ around $x_0$ to linear order. Note that in one dimension, the linear function $L$ will simply be multiplication by a constant.

You probably have two questions in mind. First, why would we want to do this? And second, what does *best* approximate even mean?

To answer the first question, we are often interested in the *leading* approximation to $f(x)$ with $x$ close to $x_0$. If you are familiar with the Taylor series, you will know that many smooth functions can be written as
$$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x - x_0) + \frac{f''(x_0)}{2} (x - x_0)^2 + \cdots $$
You can observe in the above expression that when $x$ is very close to $x_0$ (i.e. $|x - x_0|$ is small), first two terms dominate. For example, is $x - x_0$ was say, $0.01$, then the first correction (the second term) would be a correction on the order of $1 \%$, while the second correction is a on the order of $0.01 \%$, which is much smaller. (The following corrections are even smaller!)

Answering the second question gets us to the crux of your question. A *best* linear approximation is intuitively one that captures fully the effect to linear order of deviating from $x_0$. More formally, we want $L$ to be the linear function such that
$$|f(x) - f(x_0) - L(x - x_0)| < |f(x) - f(x_0) - L'(x - x_0)|$$
for any other linear function $L'$, so long as $|x - x_0|$ is small enough. From this it follows that $f(x) - f(x_0) - L(x - x_0)$ should decay faster than linearly in $x - x_0$. If instead it decayed to linear order, say
$$f(x) - f(x_0) - L(x - x_0) = L'(x - x_0) + o\left(x - x_0\right)$$
for some linear function $L'$, then $f(x_0) + (L + L')(x - x_0)$ would be a better linear approximation, because
$$|f(x) - f(x_0) - (L + L')(x - x_0)| = o\left(x - x_0\right)$$
would eventually be smaller than
$$|f(x) - f(x_0) - L (x - x_0)| = \Theta(x - x_0)$$
as $x - x_0$ becomes smaller and smaller.

In higher dimensions, the same motivation holds: we want a mathematical construct that will help us "linearize" a function around some point $\mathbf{x_0}$. The same definition of "best" holds: we want some linear transformation $L = \nabla f$ such that for all other linear transformations $L'$,
$$|f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x_0}) - L(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0})| < |f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x_0}) - L' (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0})|$$
and using similar logic, you can deduce that
$$f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{x_0}) - L(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0})$$
must decay faster than linearly.

Comment: I appreciate the counterexample that shows why my definition is wrong. Also, I understand that the components of a definition cannot always explained immediately (one may need to advance further in their studies to understand why they were put there), but why must $f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{x}) - \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \cdot \mathbf{h}$ decay faster than linear? The counterexample you gave shows what happens when its not, but it does not give a reason why it must be.

Comment: @user_hello1 Please see my edits. The addendum is a little long, but I hope it helps - and feel free to ask any follow up questions! Note that $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x_0}$ plays the role of $\mathbf{h}$.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to the direct question (not the details of the formulas).

The definition of the derivative requires a limit. Limits make sense only if you have some way of measuring the distance between vectors, so that you can say when those distances are small. In single variable calculus vectors are numbers and the absolute value measures distance. The corresponding construction in $n$-space is the norm.